# Use nested objects in form and submit to controller

Tags: javascript, html, .net

How can we submit the the nested objects with form

This is my class i want to bind .WizardDto is my model. And i want to bind a hidden field for property "choice.ChoiceList"

[image]

This is my html. I bind the hidden field for name "choice.ChoiceList"

[image]

This is where i assign values for hidden

[image]

But it comes null to controller

[image]